# employee.hashCode() Vs employee.getClass().hashcode() in Java

Tags: java, class, hashcode

I have below program.

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee("Raghav1", 101);

Employee employee2 = new Employee("Raghav", 100);

// #1
System.out.println(employee1.hashCode() == employee2.hashCode()); 

// #2
System.out.println(employee1.getClass().hashCode() == employee2.getClass().hashCode());
```

The statement 1 returns `false` as both employee objects are different but why  the statement 2 returns `true`.

Can anyone explain the difference between the above statements?

Comment: One if comparing the hashCodes of the two employees. They're different objects, and you haven't overridden hashCode(), so they have a different hashCode. The second one is comparing the hashCode of their class. And they both have the same class: Employee.

Comment: You haven't overridden the `hashCode` method in `Employee`.

Comment: I got the point suggested by you. But If I am creating two objects of employee class, then both would be saved in heap area at different locations as both have different hashcode.  What is the case of employee.getClass(), where does it saved in memory.

Answer (score 7):

The first statement compares the hash code of two employee instances. This is probably a bad implementation of the `hashCode()` method, since it seems as though both instances should be equal, and hence should have equal hash codes.

The second statement gets the class of each instance and compares the hash codes of the **classes**. Since both `employee1` and `employee2` are instances of `Employee`, they both have the same class, and you're just comparing two calls to the same `hashCode()` method, which are bound to return the same value.

Comment: I have changed the both employee objects but still the statement 2 is returning true. Could you please explain this.

Comment: @Pankaj these are still two instances of the same **class**.

Answer (score 6):

Let's guess the output of below expression:

```
Object obj = new Object();
System.out.println(obj.hashCode() == obj.hashCode());
```

Obviously `true` right? Because irrespective of you implementing the `hashCode()` or not, the consecutive `hashCode()` calls on the same instance will always return the same `int` value, provided you have not altered the state of the instance in-between.

A class once loaded into the JVM memory is also an instance by itself. Remember I'm not talking about the instances you create by `new` keyword, `Employee.class` itself is an instance of `java.lang.Class` class which is created implicitly by JVM when any class having reference to `Employee.class` is loaded or you can take as an example the class instance that will be returned by `Class.forName("Employee.class")` method.

You can even access all Object class methods on the class instances too. Such as `Employee.class.toString()`, `Employee.class.getClass()`, etc.
Now in your statement #2, both of your instances returns the reference to the same class instance that's why your expression returns true.